# How to ban someone from accessing my asp.net admin page after a couple of fails?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have an asp.net website (not mvc) and i need to **ban** a person if he tried to enter the *admin page* and failed a couple of times. How could i achieve that programatically and **efficiently**?

I know that i can ban someone's ip but he could use a proxy server or a vpn.

Just for your info :
I would like to store my banned ips in a sql-server database.I know how to do it.

**Edit:**
Also if I ban an account the banned person could just make a new account so neither ip bans or account bans are good solutions.So correct me if I am wrong but neither **account bans** or **ip bans** would work.

Comment: Typically there is a "locked out" flag on user tables for that purpose. What kind of access control are you using?

Comment: i am not using access control i am securing my admin page by 2fa.I dont have accounts in my site.

Comment: I'd love to know how you have 2fa without accounts. But if you don't have a user identity then I don't see a way to ban someone.

Comment: @AhmedAyman Trying banning them using the given  ip

Comment: what if he uses a vpn?

Comment: @Crowcoder sorry it is not 2fa it is google authenticator it is that i used to call it that with my other applications.

Comment: Sounds like your app doesn't have [`roles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5k850zwb.aspx) - it should. That way, _authentication_ (internal or 3rd party) is separate from _authorization_ (access to resources - like "admin", etc).  It's a broad topic however, so hopefully this gives you a start at a possible solution. Hth

Comment: how could i add roles when there are no user accounts and i am the only admin

Answer (score 0):

You may add Windows Events to work to you.

Using the right script in Powershell you can check Windows Event Logs to get the wrong authentications and ban them through the Firewall rules. This kind of procedure works better when using MS-SQL, since SQL create its own "bad login" events.

I mean:

1- check event log to see if there are some status codes to indicate "wrong login" - it can be done via a Schedule, (for instance on every 5 minutes) calling a Powershell script to check the correct LOG files.

2- if there are some events, copy the IP and set it into Firewall rules (IN and OUT). For instance, put the detected IP in a BLOCK rule, at any TCP port.

3- I recommend log these IP's in a text file to see, at the final of some time (day, week) which IP's were banned. Clean them for a time basis (eg. one time per month).

Comment: I dont really know how to achieve that could you please explain step by step or at least some references for how to do it.

Comment: And how could I use Windows Event and PowerShell on a server.I am making a asp.net website not an app.I dont know if I can use them on a Server.

Comment: @AhmedAyman, try Google "powershell event log" and you will find a lot of tips and hints to achieve you want. There is no "ready-to-use" formula, you must adapt and program what you need.

Comment: I have looked into it and noticed that i will also ban using the IP according to your answer.The user could use a VPN or a Proxy.What should I do in that case?

Comment: @AhmedAyman, you can detect and ban every IP that could cause "unauthorized login" for more than 5 consecutive times, for instance. And, to avoid ban some IP's recognized as true (legitimate user), you may create a "white-list" or (what I prefer) just clean the black-list in a time basis - like once at month or quarter.

Comment: Okay I figured it out : I would not give access to the admin page for users who are using vpns or proxies using an api from the internet then I would do your suggestion.Thanks for your help